# Why does Yuno fall for Yuki in the first place?

Tags: mirai-nikki

It occurred to me that in the whole anime, there is never any reason mentioned for why she falls in love with Yuki. I mean, the first Yuno from the first dimension loved him as much as the Yuno from the second dimension and so on the third (probably). But there was never any explanation for why that made her like him so much. Is there anything that explain that in the manga? or somewhere else?

Comment: Been a long time since I watched it but If I recall correctly Yuki approached her on the past I don't remember the reason but since then she had the feeling there is also the another universe occurrence. But I don't recall enough to make it an accurate answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Darjeeling's [answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/7886) is right about the things that made Yuno falls for Yuki, but as far as I remember, there's deeper truth behind that:

> Yuki wanted to go stargazing with his family, but his parent got divorced. So Yuno answered that she will be his bride, his family, so that Yuki's wish might come true. And to Yuno's answer, Yuki replied that they had to become adult first. The important thing was, later it was told that, at that time, Yuno's parents HAD already dies. She might seem OK, but she had actually fallen deep into despair, thinking that there's no future for her. And that was where the stargazing conversation happened, in which Yuki (kinda) promised to take her as his bride. Thus, that event gave her a new hope, a future as Yuki's wife.

So, without Yuki himself realizing, at that time, he saved Yuno with his words, and that event became a life support for Yuno.

I forgot the chapter of manga where that complete reason is revealed, but for sure it's not an early chapters, since a big, big secret

> The story about how Yuno's parents death

has to be revealed first. Though I remember that when it was revealed, Yuki himself realized that

> "So I've became her only moral support..." or something along that line

Comment: @ShinobuOshino It seems like this answer with the most common sense. Anyway I can without doubt say that is the anime with the largest number of plot holes I ever seen.

Comment: @HashiramaSenju Aaaa I found it! It's on vol 11 Diary53! (ch 53)

Comment: @HashiramaSenju also read vol 08 Diary34, this one even better, because it tells about that event from Yuno's P.O.V.

Comment: @zargin I didn't really seen anything that makes more sense in this from what you have explain in your answer... can you be more specific?

Comment: @HashiramaSenju Nothing, just in case you wanna read it.

Answer (score 7):

The reason is simple and a little bit ridiculous. It explain on chapter 5:

> Because Yuki said he want to stargaze with his family, but his parent broke that promise to buy him a telescope because they got divorce. And then Yuno said that she will become his bride (so she can become his family) to watch a star with him. And Yuki (jokingly) answer that she have to wait until they're grown up, and Yuno accept that statement seriously.

these are pages on chapter 5, click to enlarge picture, page order: left to right

> [image: page 23 of chapter 5] [image: page 25 of chapter 5] [image: page 26 of chapter 5] [image: page 27 of chapter 5]

It's Yuno, she's yandere and crazy stalker. So I think it's reasonable for her to fall in love with Yuki because of such a reason like that

Comment: It's really doesn't explain why would she be loved *so much* just because of that single reason, And why she stalk him so long before she could at least said she interested in him  (or show him any clue that she is)...

Comment: @HashiramaSenju just like I said, it's Yuno, she can kill people with smile in her face, you can't expect logic from a Yandere. And if you want to go deeper, see Zargin's answer.

Comment: @HashiramaSenju You can accept another answer if you want, after I reread the manga, Zargin's answer is more correct. anyway, about why she stalk him so long, it's probably because she doesn't know that Yuki will love her back, she only know it because her future diary tells her about it. She doesn't sure, so she only stalk him and didn't do anything about it

Comment: oh, Now that make perfect sense (almost =]) you mean because she didn't know if he will love her back, she stalk him for know him better until she got her diary and then 'and only then' she approach him because the diary said that he will definitely love her back?

Comment: yepp, that's most definitely it. Remember when Yuno first kiss with Yuki and she said that he won't stab her (first chapter), she know it because of her future diary. And the same diary said they will be bound together. Maybe she afraid she will kill him if Yuki didn't love her back?

Comment: like i've said earlier, this is the anime with the most plot holes i've ever seen =/

Answer (score 0):

There's also the fact that we're dealing with 1st world Yuno here. That is, the untold story of the 1st World Survival Game. The 1st world Yuki might have been "cooler" than the 2nd world as he might have not relied on Yuno that much. Her feelings from that stargazing even might me reinforced more by the events of the 1st world Survival Game. And when she came to the Second World resulted to a "crazed Yandere Queen" Yuno for killing her beloved 1st world Yuki and not being able to resurrect him with the godly powers she acquired. (The key is to know that we're dealing with a mentally unstable girl who killed her adoptive parents and her lover.)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be her mental illness called stockholm syndrome that she has,definition-feelings of trust or affection felt in certain cases of kidnapping or hostage-taking by a victim toward a captor.